# Spring boot application not up and run when start even using IDE(eclipse) or command prompt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

Just create a spring boot app in eclipse and try to run it , but it is not started properly as enough to handle a request . following shows the console 
Tried all the solutions of other questions asked on same issue. but not worked.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.6.RELEASE)

2018-10-22 14:12:42.929  INFO 5752 --- [           main] com.nevro.TrainingApiApp                 : Starting TrainingApiApp on DESKTOP-AUANCVF with PID 5752 (E:\MyStuff\Tutorials\spring-boot-training\target\classes started by acer in E:\MyStuff\Tutorials\spring-boot-training)
2018-10-22 14:12:42.932  INFO 5752 --- [           main] com.nevro.TrainingApiApp                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-22 14:12:43.004  INFO 5752 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19d37183: startup date [Mon Oct 22 14:12:43 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-22 14:12:43.758  INFO 5752 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-22 14:12:43.770  INFO 5752 --- [           main] com.nevro.TrainingApiApp                 : Started TrainingApiApp in 1.137 seconds (JVM running for 1.725)
2018-10-22 14:12:43.783  INFO 5752 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19d37183: startup date [Mon Oct 22 14:12:43 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-22 14:12:43.785  INFO 5752 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

It says application started but when try to brows it, nothing other than error in browser.

default port for tomcat (8080) is unoccupied .

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nevro</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-training</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-theory training</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Here is Main class with main method

```
package com.nevro;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TrainingApiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TrainingApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Have a one controller too as follows

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHi(){
        return "hi";
    }


}
```

Any reason for this and how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to visit `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8080/hello`?

Comment: I tried both localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/hello

Comment: Move your controller to `com.nevro.controller` instead of just `controller`. The controller isn't detected in the current package. If that still doesn't work you might want to purge your local repository, `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, and rebuild the system to download fresh dependencies.

Comment: @Lasan Please provide the error that you are getting.

Comment: @M.Deinum your 2 steps  which are  1. rename package controller to com.nevro.controller 2. purging local repository using mvn dependency:purge-local-repository command sort out the issue . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.Deinum post it as an answer, so it can be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot will automatically detect all beans in the `com.nevro` and sub packages. However your controller is in the `controller` package and as such will never be detected. Move the controller to the `com.nevro.controller` package, this will make Spring Boot detect the controller and will help decide if a web server needs to be started.

It can also be that one of the dependencies isn’t correctly downloaded. You might want to purge the local repository using `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, then rebuild the application to re-download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a controller, try adding one. I've included a very basic example below.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

> The class is flagged as a @RestController, meaning it’s ready for use by Spring MVC to handle web requests. @RequestMapping maps / to the index() method. When invoked from a browser or using curl on the command line, the method returns pure text. That’s because @RestController combines @Controller and @ResponseBody, two annotations that results in web requests returning data rather than a view.

Source: [Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

After adding the controller restart your application and visit `localhost:8080/`, you should now see `Greetings from Spring Boot!`.

Comment: Thanx for replay I am having a controller as well. I just added to the question it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the package of your controller: `package controller;`

Your main class is in other package: `package com.nevro;` so when Spring Boot tries to find the controllers it doesn't find anything

Answer (score -1):

Try with some other port number by adding the following line in application.properties:

```
server.port = 8088
```

And if this still not works, then change the JDK version you installed.

**For spring boot 2, you need jdk 9.**

Comment: I just sorted out the issue by following 2 steps given by @M.Deinum 

  1. rename package controller to com.nevro.controller 
  2. purging local repository using mvn dependency:purge-local-repository 
   command sort out the issue . 
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: That's not true. Java 8 is supported in Spring Boot 2. However versions older than Java 7 is not.